# Trying to run SQL Server trigger in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run this trigger that works successfully in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio in a PHPMyAdmin SQL 'script' window for an application that runs with mysql. Just wondered if anyone knew of the correct syntax to use in this instance - I keep on getting errors saying 'You have an error in your SQL Syntax...near the 'on' clause blah blah blah!

```
USE AP;
Go
CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_test1 on dbo.test2

AFTER UPDATE
AS

UPDATE dbo.test1
  SET test1.customer_deleted_at = inserted.store_deleted_at
FROM dbo.test1
JOIN inserted ON inserted.store_id = test1.store_id
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server and MySql are completely different RDBMS systems. You cannot expect tsql code to work on MySql except the ANSI SQL Syntax which is generally compatible on most DBMS Systems.

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER upd_check 
       ON test2
       AFTER UPDATE 
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
          UPDATE test1
          SET customer_deleted_at = new.store_deleted_at
          WHERE store_id = new.store_id;
       END;//
```